# git latexdiff – ignore files from tar-ing

Tags: git, tar

tl;dr: How can I exclude files from git-latexdiff packaging, preferably with wildcards.

I've continuing problems with git latexdiff not being able to package up files when comparing against the local working copy. I.e, for a given repository `git latexdiff -o changes.pdf --main manuscript.tex submission_01`
works, whereas

```
git latexdiff -o changes.pdf --main manuscript.tex submission_01 --
```

does not.

This is due to tar errors on files that are not even relevant for the latexdiff, so I should like to be able to exclude them (if not have git-latexdiff make it work for me;-)

Error message:

```
tar: "2019-09-24 publisher email.txt": Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

It would be a good solution to be able to simply make git-latexdiff ignore such files from the diff, e.g., everything with filenames `"20*"` – any possibility to do this?

I could not find it in the git-latexdiff help/manuals... :-()